# How to scaffold a Class Library targeting .NET Core?

Tags: c#, class-library, .net-core, .net-core-rc2, dotnet-cli

I know that using Visual Studio there is a template to create a Class Library targeting .NET Core, but I'm looking for a way to do it from the command line.

I know that using `dotnet new` you can create a new .NET core project, but it is a console application that has a few more dependencies than the class library created by Visual Studio. Is there a command or way to create a class library project from the command line?

Eg: [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dotnet new now supports arguments one of them is --type -t where you can specify: console, web, lib and xunittest.

So now you can do:

`dotnet new --type lib`

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-new

Answer (score 3):

The [Writing Libraries with .NET Core](http://dotnet.github.io/docs/core-concepts/libraries/libraries-with-cli.html) article has a lot of great detail that is non-Visual Studio specific.

There isn't currently a way to scaffold a new class library via `dotnet new`, but you can do it yourself. At a very minimum, you need a folder with a `project.json` file containing:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.5.0-rc2-24027"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.3": { }
  },
  "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

When you compile using `dotnet build`, this will produce a class library targeting [.NET Platform Standard 1.3](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md#mapping-the-net-platform-standard-to-platforms).

It's my understanding that the dotnet-cli tool will be [updated](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/2052) to include this template eventually.

**Edit:** As @svick pointed out, the [Yeoman generator](https://github.com/OmniSharp/generator-aspnet/pull/609) for ASP.NET Core can do this! You can scaffold a library with `yo aspnet classlibrary` in the latest version.

Comment: All right great to hear that, for the time being i will proceed in this way, Thank you @Nate

Comment: @svick Not with RC2 [yet](https://github.com/OmniSharp/generator-aspnet/issues/601). Should be coming soon.

Comment: @NateBarbettini That links to [this PR](https://github.com/OmniSharp/generator-aspnet/pull/609), which has been merged for a while. And `yo aspnet classlibrary` works for me a creates an RC2 project.